# How to say "I don't want to take the risk of not being repaid by you"?

Tags: translation

Someone asked me to lend money but I want to reject his request by saying:

> I don't want to take the risk of not being repaid by you.

How to say it in Japanese?

My attempt is as follows:

> あなたが返さないリスクを取りたくないです。

Does it sound natural?

## Note:

Indirectness is not necessarily needed in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> あなたが返さないリスクを取りたくないです。

This would surely make yourself understood, but there is a small room for improvement. Saying あなた is not really common in Japanese, as you probably know.

Instead, you can say "お金が返ってこないリスク" or "お金を返してくれないリスク" (without あなた).

This statement will sound very "direct", as you can guess. Please use at your own risk.

Comment: How about お金を返してくれられないリスクを取りたくないです。?

Comment: The "くれられる" part sounds very weird to me.

Comment: その感じで言うと，「お金を返してもらえない」 is fine.

Comment: Is リスク a word you can often encounter in daily informal conversations? Or does it have a kind of official feel to it?